# How can I stop Rider from showing the .sln file or .csproj files when I select the solution or project in Rider's Explorer?

Tags: rider

In Rider, when I select the solution or a project in its Explorer view, it automatically opens the .sln or .csproj file in the editor. While I sometimes want to look or edit .csproj files, that's the exception rather than the norm.

Can I disable this "feature" of Rider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable `Autoscroll to source` in the solution explorer settings (under the gear icon or via solution explorer toolbar).

We have a feature request to customize autoscroll behavior, feel free to track the status:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-17295

I hope I will find time and fix it in 2019.2 release cycle.